# can you help me write a code for all 'ht' from the ytop and ybot values in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

Can anyone please help me write this code for all 'ht' in matlab?.
Thank you.

```
ytop=[0 0 2.4 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0]
  ybot=[0 -2.4 -3.9 -4.7 -4.9 -4.7 -3.8 -2.3 0.1 5.0]
  ht=((ytop(2)-ybot(2))+(ytop(1)-ybot(1)))/2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to do `((ytop(i)-ybot(i))+(ytop(i-1)-ybot(i-1)))/2` for all `i` then just use element-wise operations and a bit of indexing:

```
((ytop(2:end) - ybot(2:end))./((ytop(1:end-1) - ybot(1:end-1)))/2
```

Comment: aahhh really, I just overthink about it :D

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you need calculate `ht` for each index you can go this way:

```
fun = @(x) ((ytop(x)-ybot(x))+(ytop(x-1)-ybot(x-1)))/2
ind = 2:10
result = arrayfun(fun, ind)
```

and get this result:

```
result =
1.2000    4.3500    8.0000    9.8000    9.8000    9.2500    8.0500    6.1000    2.4500
```

Comment: thank you all guys. it was helpful